# Can't pass args from c# console app to .bat file

Tags: c#, batch-file

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Visual\ConsoleApp\FirstConsole\FirstConsole\RunSqlBat.bat");//Path of the .bat file

string sqlPath = @"C:\Sln\DevDatabase\Algorithm.sql";//Path of sql file I run using bat file
psi.Arguments =args[0]+ " " + args[1] + " " + args[2] + " " + args[3] + " " + sqlPath;//Passing arguments
psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;

System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
p.Start();
p.Kill();
System.Console.Read();
```

The .bat file is

```
sqlcmd -S %1 -d %2 -U %3 -P %4 -i %5
pause
```

The values are not passed to the bat file.(When the run the bat file in cmd it is working fine)

When I opened the cmd prompt gave FirstConsole.exe serverName DatabaseName userName Password

```
Error as
sqlcmd:'-s':Missing argument
```

How to pass the arguments to the .bat file

Note : I have already used

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments =string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], sqlPath);
```

Comment: Replace `sqlcmd` with `echo` to see what is exported. Use `>1` at the end of `echo` to copy that into file `1`. You are using `Arguments` correctly (both approaches should work), but we have no idea what `args[0]` contains now (show it?) and what it should (show what you want).

Comment: yeah check args[0] is not empty

Comment: .sql of mine performs actions on 3 tables and it is doing it properly...only issue is that it is giving me an extra row success

Comment: 140 rows affected 140 rows affected 0 rows affected 0 rows affected      14 rows affected 14 rows affected 14 rows affected....Is there some thing in the code causing this?

Comment: What is your question? Is the argument passing working or is it not? It sounds like you're asking us to debug the sql statement that isn't even part of your question...

Comment: it is passing alright....after the execution of sql file when I get the results it showing the above...note the last 14 rows affected is a extra row getting displayed